# Default implementations VS inherited methods in Java 8

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java 8 we were introduced to a feature called "[Default Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)"

How does Java behave when i try this:

An Interface that has an implementation of `doStuff`

```
public interface MyInterface {
    default void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("MyInterface ");
    };
}
```

And an abstract class that has an implementation of `doStuff`

```
public abstract class MyAbstract {
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("MyAbstract ");
    };
}
```

And a class that extends the abstract class and implements my interface:

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstract implements MyInterface {
    //this can just be empty
}
```

Does this even compile? If so, what will be printed when:

```
new MyClass().doStuff();
```

Comment: Your questions can be answered by simply typing this out and then trying to compile/run it. No need for us to do that for you.

Comment: cant do that at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Does this even compile?

Yes

- If so, what will be printed when... ?

It will print `MyAbstract`

- How does Java behave when I try this:

If the function is not implemented in your class/its parent class, then and only then the default method will be executed. Comment out the method `doStuff()` in abstract class and then you have `MyInterface` printed out. This way, if someone adds a default method to an interface that you had already implemented with the same method name of a method in your class/parent class, your implementation is not broken